# The names of $\Bbb{G}_a$ and $\Bbb{G}_m$

Tags: notation, group-schemes

By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme#Examples), over a field $k$, $\Bbb{G}_a=k$ and $\Bbb{G}_m=k^*$ as scheme over $k$. My question is why these group schemes calles "the additive group scheme" and "the multiplicative group scheme" respectively.

Comment: To be a group requires an identity element and inverses for the group operation.  A field is a group with respect to the operation of addition, but in order to have a group with respect to the operation of multiplication, we need to "omit" the zero element.  The notation $k^*$ signifies that multiplicative group.  Perhaps all this is known to you?

Comment: Yes, I (of course) know. But why are they being called *the* multiplicative\additive group scheme?

Comment: In the context of that Examples section of the article the *definite* article "the" signifies only that what follows is uniquely identified. The preceding Constructions section amply illustrates that $\mathbf G_m$ is not the only group scheme of *multiplicative type*, so it is only describing one example among many as a multiplicative type group scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will illustrate the multiplicative group as example, the additive group being similar.

The scheme $\Bbb G_m$ has the following property: given any field extension $K/k$, we have a natural bijection between the set of $K$-rational points $\Bbb G_m(K)$ and $K^*$, the multiplicative group of the field $K$. Moreover, the group structure of $\Bbb G_m$ translates exactly to the group structure of $K^*$.

In other words, taking $K$-rational points of $\Bbb G_m$ "produces" the multiplicative group of the field $K$: $$\Bbb G_m(K)``="\text{multiplicative group of }K.$$
It therefore makes sense to call $\Bbb G_m$ "the multiplicative group scheme".